How to format numbers on big query?
I've gone deep through big query documentation but found nothing about my issue.
I would like to know how to format numbers in big query with and without decimals and with currency symbols .
Ex: 100000000 -> R$1,000,000.00

Check formatting of numeric types as strings - link
WITH my_data AS (SELECT 100000000 AS value)
SELECT CAST(value/100 AS STRING FORMAT '$999,999,999,999.99') 
FROM my_data



CAST the column within the query as a string and then format that string: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_currency_symbol
e.g.
SELECT
  CAST(column_a AS STRING FORMAT '$99') as a,
  CAST(column_b AS STRING FORMAT '$99') as b;

/*------+------*
 | a    | b    |
 +------+------+
 |  $12 | -$12 |
 *------+------*/

